# pass an object as props

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm working on a little project using VueJS, and I would like to know how can I print my props (label) that I'm receiving

this is my code :

```
<div class="form-group">
     <auto-complete :path="'/api/accounts/autoComplete/'" :label="'item.account_name'"></auto-complete>
</div>
```

this is my component HTML :

```
    <template>
    <div class="autocomplete">
        <input autocomplete="off" type="text" class="form-control form-control-border" placeholder="query" v-model="query" @input="autoComplete" @focus="suggestion = true" />
        <div v-if="data && suggestion">
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton1">
                <li @click="selected(item.account_name)" v-for="item in data" :key="item.id">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">{{ label }}</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
import {getAPI} from "../axios-api"

export default {
    props: {
        label: Object,
        path: String
    },
    data() {
        return {
            suggestion: false,
            query: '',
            data: [],
        }
    },
    methods: {
        autoComplete(){
            if(/\S/.test(this.query) && this.query.length >= 3){
                getAPI.get(this.path + '?query=' + this.query).then((response) => {
                    this.data = response.data
                })
            }
        },
        selected(account){
            this.query = account
            this.suggestion = false
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

as you can see I'm sending an object in :label that i want to print here ( since i have this object in my component data )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you want a specific key of `item` as the label, you can just pass that key string then use it in your dropdown item. Make sure that the `label` prop accepts only `String`.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <auto-complete path="/api/accounts/autoComplete/" label="account_name" placeholder="My PlaceHolder"></auto-complete>
</div>
```

```
<template>
  <input autocomplete="off" type="text" class="form-control form-control-border" :placeholder="placeholder" v-model="query" @input="autoComplete" @focus="suggestion = true" />

  <li @click="selected(item.account_name)" v-for="item in data" :key="item.id">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">{{ item[label] }}</a>
  </li>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    label: String,
    placeholder: String
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: already did it but the same issue, please see my :label   what i'm sending

Comment: Please edit the post to show the complete component code.

Comment: @jrcmatog  updated :)     by the way i want to re-use my component and each time show a different field

Comment: must i add :  before  label ?

Comment: thank you, what if i want to v-bind:placeholder=" {{ path }} "

Comment: @AliceMunin Where would you use the placeholder/path?

Comment: in my inpute placeholder    like that   <input type"text"  placeholder="  path here " >

Comment: Assuming the value of `path` is `/api/accounts/autoComplete/`, you want that to be the input's placeholder?

Comment: yes correct or for example i want to  send  another props called placeholder like i'm sending path

Comment: i did also  placeholder="this.placeholder"  in my component  works fine also

Answer (score 0):

You are sending string, not object.
You should do:

```
:label="item.account_name"
```

Instead of

```
:label="'item.account_name'"
```

Comment: can you double see my code updated  :) 
i want to re use my auto complete and each time show a different label ( it depends on my table fields

Comment: Yeah, I suppose you register the auto-complete component correctly. 
If so, you should be able to use it. Just make sure you the `item.account_name` not `'item.account_name'` into :label